# Erlang and C library. Parallel execution

Tags: parallel-processing, erlang

How can I call C library from Erlang in parallel way ?

I have C library, which supports multi-threading(mutex inside) and I want to launch this library from thousands of threads from erlang in truly parallel way. How can I do it ?

Can I achieve this via Erlang C Port Drivers or via C Nodes or NIFs ?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by call C library and what kind of library? Is it thread safe library? Just call it in NIF. If it doesn't, then you have to restrict access to the shared state by mutex or lock as usual. There is not any magic bullet in Erlang. What Erlang provides you is tools for managing it in a meaningful way.

Comment: I mean call threadsafe functions from my C library. NIFs has running time restrictions in 0.1ms and that's not suitable for me.

Comment: @EduardBondarenko: Then you can use dirty schedulers or make your own threads. But using ports should be the preferred way unless you have really strong performance requirements and sending a serialised data in and out would kill it.

Comment: Yep, we can't use plain ports for performance reason, so we consider to use c ports drivers. Should we work with threads in C lib ? No way to use Erlang threads ? Thx.

Comment: @EduardBondarenko: I don't know, I have always found a way how to cut work to smaller pieces and keep it under 1ms.